# Cant set Frame.Source via triggers after NavigationCommands.GoToPage is used

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to create a MVVM-ready custom control that extends Frame (from Navigation), with two primary goals in mind.

Firstly, I want to be able to change the Source of the frame via triggers. This way, I can change *which view* is used based for some cases when a property of the ViewModel changes.

Secondly, I want the views themselves to be able to change *which view* is used, for certain cases where nothing in the ViewModel changes. Using a Frame/Page system and calling the NavigationCommands.GoToPage Command from inside the pages seemed to be the most appropriate way to do this, since each different view can be defined as a page.

The problem I'm running into is that setting Frame.Source via triggers works perfectly fine until the first time GoToPage is used. After that, the triggers seem to have no effect. GoToPage appears to work all of the time, any time. I've been searching all day and can't find any documentation that explains this.

Anyhow, here's the implementation for my custom Frame, where all I do is bind to GoToPage and ensure Pages inherit DataContext:

```
public class FrameExtended : Frame
{
    public FrameExtended()
    {
        CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(NavigationCommands.GoToPage, GoToPage_Executed));
        Navigated += new System.Windows.Navigation.NavigatedEventHandler(FrameExtended_Navigated);
    }

    void FrameExtended_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        (Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this.DataContext;
    }

    void GoToPage_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Parameter is Uri) Source = e.Parameter as Uri;
        else if (e.Parameter is string) Source = new Uri(e.Parameter as string, UriKind.Relative);
    }
}
```

Here's a test case for my ViewModel, which is about as simple as a ViewModel gets:

```
public enum MyEnum { MyEnumVal1, MyEnumVal2, MyEnumVal3 }

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private MyEnum enumVal = MyEnum.MyEnumVal1;

    public MyEnum EnumVal
    {
        get { return enumVal; }
        set
        {
            if (enumVal != value)
            {
                enumVal = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("EnumVal");
            }
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

And here's test snippet of XAML where I employ the frame and define a few triggers:

```
<Button Content="ChangeViewModel" Click="Button_Click"/>
<Control>
    <Control.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Control">
            <local:FrameExtended x:Name="MyFrame"/>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EnumVal}" Value="MyEnumVal1">
                    <Setter TargetName="MyFrame" Property="Source" Value="Pages/testpage.xaml"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EnumVal}" Value="MyEnumVal2">
                    <Setter TargetName="MyFrame" Property="Source" Value="Pages/testpage2.xaml"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EnumVal}" Value="MyEnumVal3">
                    <Setter TargetName="MyFrame" Property="Source" Value="Pages/testpage3.xaml"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="MyFrame" Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Control.Template>
</Control>
```

Where Button_Click refers to:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var vm = this.DataContext as ViewModel;

    switch (vm.EnumVal)
    {
        case MyEnum.MyEnumVal1: vm.EnumVal = MyEnum.MyEnumVal2; break;
        case MyEnum.MyEnumVal2: vm.EnumVal = MyEnum.MyEnumVal3; break;
        case MyEnum.MyEnumVal3: vm.EnumVal = MyEnum.MyEnumVal1; break;
    }
}
```

Aside from that, testpage.xaml contains the following line:

```
<Button Content="NEXTPAGE" Command="GoToPage" CommandParameter="Pages/testpage2.xaml"/>
```

Where the rest of the pages just have a TextBlock indicating which page it is.

If I click the "ChangeViewModel" button over and over again, the frame will cycle through the pages as expected (and changing its background to green when it's on page 3). Once I click the button inside testpage.xaml that calls GoToPage, the Frame switches to testpage2. After that, subsequent clicks on ChangeViewModel never change which page is displayed, but still make the Frame's background green every 3rd click (when testpage3 should show).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I've found for this issue is to use Frame.Navigate() in my GoToPage handler defined in the custom control, instead of setting the source property directly. It seems to be that setting the Source property from C# code is what prevents triggers from changing it (different priority levels, I guess). Navigate() doesn't have this issue, and it's actually what I tried first and is most likely the ideal implementation. It didn't work before because all of these implementations were in a Control Library and Navigate() was searching for my pages in the executing assembly instead. As a side note for anyone else trying to do something similar, be sure to include the assembly reference in any URI you pass to Frame.Navigate(), as it will otherwise search in the executing assembly by default (not necessarily the defining assembly, as with URIs specified in XAML). My GoToPage handler now looks like this:

```
void GoToPage_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Parameter is Uri) Navigate(e.Parameter as Uri);
    else if (e.Parameter is string) Navigate(new Uri(e.Parameter as string, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}
```